# ReactJS - Using a Search Bar to navigate to different pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

im working on a project. I have a bunch of pages ive created and i want a user to be able to use a search bar to find those pages relating to their search. Does anyone have an idea on how to go about this?

Comment: it does not include any code details or the efforts (try) you have done so far at this moment, so it could be hard for people to give you solutions that fit your demand directly.

Comment: Maybe you can make the searched result a list of links that could route to the corresponding pages?

Comment: I could include my code but right now it’s just HTML and CSS with no JavaScript at the moment, so I think the only useful thing I could provide is the files/components I have in my editor? And that’s what I want to do but I don’t know how I can make a searched list of results depending on what the user inputs. Thank you keikai